# point wise and uniform convergence of function series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, uniform-convergence

i need some help to understand point wise and uniformly convergence and solve the following:

Let f be a series of functions defined by  $f_n(x) := \dfrac{1}{n}e^{-n²x²}$.

Show that

1. $f'_n(x)$ converges point wise on $[0, 1]$
2. but not uniformly.
3. compute $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}f'_n(x)$ and $(\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}f_n(x))'$

My results so far:

1. $$
   \ f_n(x) := \dfrac{1}{n}e^{-n²x²} \Rightarrow f'_n(x) := -2nx\dfrac{1}{e^{n²x²}}
   $$
   For x = 0:
   $$
   \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}f'_n(0)=0
   $$
   For x = 1:
   $$
   \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}f'_n(1)=\dfrac{-2n}{e^{n²}}=0
   $$

   > How i have to argue now that $f'_n$ converges point wise?
2. $f'_n$ doesn't converge uniformly:
   $$
   Definition \  of \ uniformly\ convergence \ says: \\
   \forall \epsilon >0 \exists N \in \mathbb{N}: | f_n(x) -f(x)| < \epsilon\ ,\  \forall n\geq N\ and \ \forall x\in \mathbb{D}
   $$
   so i have to show that
   $$
   \exists \epsilon >0 \ that \ \forall N \in \mathbb{N} \exists n>N: | f_n(x) -f(x)| > \epsilon\ ,\  n\geq N\ and \ x\in \mathbb{D}
   $$

   > can someone explain or give me some hints how i have to apply this def. to show that $f'_n$ doesnt converge uniformly?
3. Both limits are 0.

Thanks,
Landau

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the case where $x \neq 0, 1$, you can observe that asymptotically, an exponential function majorates any polynomial function, one key fact for taking limits. Proof of it, if you want it:
   http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Exponential_Dominates_Polynomial
2. Suggestion: Take the second derivative of $f_n$, and use it to find a maxima for $f_n'$, which you will observe does not depend on $n$... Then draw your conclusion.

More thoroughly, $$f_n'' (x) = \frac{2n(2nx^2-1)}{e^{n^2x^2}}$$
has zeroes at $x = \pm 1/\sqrt{2}n$ and 
$$f_n'(1/\sqrt{2}n) = -\sqrt{2}e^{-1/2}$$
So each $f_n$ is attaining $c := -\sqrt{2}e^{-1/2}$ at some value. So I guess if $\epsilon < c$, there can't be any $N$ such that $\forall n > N$, $|f_n(x)| < \epsilon$ in the unit interval: not uniform convergence.

Comment: I wrote this in a hurry. If you have questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: thanks dude! helps me a lot! :)